# Focus on TextBox inside TabContainer

Tags: asp.net, tabs, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a custom Login screen in a Tab Container

```
     <asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true" OnActiveTabChanged="TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged" CssClass="MyTabStyle">
                <asp:TabPanel ID="uxStandardTab" runat="server" HeaderText="Login">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <table width="320px" border="0" style="border-width: 0px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <cc1:LabeledTextBox ID="Username" runat="server" Required="true" LabelText="Email/User Name" LabelWidth="120" ControlWidth="150" LabelCss="FormLabelText BoldText" ValidationGroup="Standard"></cc1:LabeledTextBox>
                                    <cc1:LabeledTextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Required="true" LabelText="Password" LabelWidth="120" ControlWidth="150" LabelCss="FormLabelText BoldText" ValidationGroup="Standard"></cc1:LabeledTextBox>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <div style="margin-top: 5px; margin-right: 20px; text-align: center;">
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Log In" CssClass="grnbutton" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="Standard" />
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

I'm trying to set focus on User Name field in the page load.

I have tried

```
var txtUserName = uxStandardTab.FindControl("UserName");
        if (txtUserName != null)
        {
            Page.SetFocus(txtUserName);
        }
```

and

```
Username.Focus();
```

But, none of them puts cursor in User Name Text box during page load.  Please advise, if Tab Control behaves differently.

Answer (score 2):

With Ajax don't use `Page.SetFocus` but [`Scriptmanager.SetFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.setfocus(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).SetFocus(txtUserName);
```

Comment: @user2169261: but you're sure that `uxStandardTab` is not `null`?

Comment: yes, uxStandardTab.FindControl("UserName") returns textbox control